# Silex 2: RegEx in routing

Tags: php, regex, routes, silex

Is it possible to use RegEx in Silex 2 routings?

I need to do something like this:

```
$this->get('/(adios|goodbay)', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('bye.html.twig', []);
})->bind('bye');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by Thomas, yes you can. The important part of the documentation are [route requirements](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#requirements):

> In some cases you may want to only match certain expressions. You can define requirements using regular expressions by calling assert on the Controller object, which is returned by the routing methods.

For example:

```
$app->get('/blog/{postId}/{commentId}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
    // ...
})
->assert('postId', '\d+')
->assert('commentId', '\d+');
```

So, in your case the definition of the route would be something like:

```
$this->get('/{bye}', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('bye.html.twig', []);
})
->assert('bye', '^(adios|goodbye)$')
->bind('bye');
```

If you also want to know the value of the parameter, just pass it to the controller (the parameter name must match the name of the parameter in the route definition):

```
$this->get('/{bye}', function (Request $request, $bye) use ($app) {
    if ($bye === 'adios') {
      $sentence = "eso es todo amigos!";
    }
    else {
      $sentence = "that's all folks!";
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('bye.html.twig', ["sentence" => $sentence]);
})
->assert('bye', '^(adios|goodbye)$')
->bind('bye');
```

Comment: And, is it possible to know from closure function if it has been called using 'adios' or 'goodbye'? Thanks

Comment: I had been thinking to migrate from Silex to Symfony (mostly due to my lack of knowledge in Silex), but little by little I see it's possible to do almost anything you easily do with Symfony.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea, keep in mind that as of Genuary 2018 [the EOL for Silex has been anounced](http://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-silex). You should try to migrate to SF4. Here's an [unofficial guide](https://medium.com/@derrabus/the-silex-sunset-d0fb5f1129df).

Comment: @mTorres thank you so much for letting me know about this article. I should keep posted of those kind of news, definitely. I'd move on to Symfony 4 then, since I'm at the beginning of my project, it makes a lot of sense to do that now, than suffer the pain of lack of support and future patches/maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [doc<sup>Page 8</sup>](https://silex.symfony.com/pdf/2.0/Silex.pdf#page=8):

> In Silex you define a route and the controller that is called when that route is matched. A route pattern consists of:
>
> - Pattern : The route pattern defines a path that points to a resource. The pattern can include variable parts and you are able to set RegExp requirements for them.

So I would say that it's possible to use regex as you did in the question.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with this "/(adios|goodbay)/" but it does not work, can you help me please?

Comment: @cybtow, can you elaborate with "it dows not work"? What HTTP status are you receiving a 404? Have you checked Silex log's (assuming you've 'debug' enabled and monolog which you should during development)?

Comment: This is the error shown NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 125: No route found for "GET /adios" when I use any of these routes: $this->get('^/(adios|goodbay)/$', $this->get('/^(adios|goodbay)$/', $this->get('/(adios|goodbay)/'. Thanks